# How can i deserialize (XML) a url field?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

My problem is the following:
I'am trying deserialize a XML doc (see it below).

---

```
offer id="68985117" categoryId="2921">
    <offerName>CD Metallica - Some Kind of Monster ( 5314040 )</offerName>
    <offerShortName>Cd Metallica Some</offerShortName>
    <links>
    <link type="offer" url="http://.."/>
    <thumbnail url="http://thumbs.buscape.com.br/T100x100/__2.81-41ca11d.jpg"/>
    <price>
    <currency abbreviation="BRL"/>
    <value>19.90</value>
```

---

I'am reading [offerName] using XML

```
offername = x.GetElementsByTagName("offerName")[0].InnerText,
```

and value by

```
offervalue = x.GetElementsByTagName("value")[0].InnerText
```

---

**My question: how can i take the link url and thumbnail url?**

Comment: Can someone post a sample code? Solutions below didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GetAttribute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7.aspx) method of XmlElement

```
string url = x.GetElementsByTagName("link")[0].GetAttribute("url");
```

Here is a complete example

```
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();

x.LoadXml("<xml goes here/>");

string offername = x.GetElementsByTagName("offerName")[0].InnerText;
string offervalue = x.GetElementsByTagName("value")[0].InnerText;

string linkUrl = x.GetElementsByTagName("link")[0].Attributes["url"].Value;
string thumb = x.GetElementsByTagName("thumbnail")[0].Attributes["url"].Value;
```

Comment: Return error: System.Xml.XmlNode does not contain a definition of GetAttribute;

Comment: cast it to an XmlElement, or use the Attributes property, which both XmlElement and XmlNode have

Comment: With XmlElement a cant load my string wich contains the entire xml code. I also cant use the GetAtributte() method on xmldocument or xml element.

Comment: As I said in my comment above, you can either cast it or use the Attributes property.  See my edited example.

Comment: If this answer helped, please take the time to mark it as "Accepted" (green check mark)

Answer (score 0):

Get the element (i.e. thumbnail) and then pick off the url attribute from the Attribute collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var thumbnailUrl =    x.GetElementsByTagName("thumbnail")[0].GetAttribute["url"].Value;
var linklUrl =    x.GetElementsByTagName("link")[0].GetAttribute["url"].Value;
```

Comment: Return error: System.Xml.XmlNode does not contain a definition of GetAttribute.